# <ul> <li> do make to rows of list

Tags: html, css

I Have 15 names, and what I want to do is to divde the names in three rows (5names on each row), at the moment Iam using `<ul>` and `<li>` tags

is there some possible way to have three rows 5 names on each row? using still the `li` and `ul` tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find a list of methods do to what you want [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/).

Comment: +1 Nice find. Though i would suggest a little more description in your answer instead of expecting the OP to follow your link. It's ok, but if many answers land, yours won't get looked at as often.

Comment: @Paul, I agree. However, there are several ways of achieving this so I figure I'd give the OP the choice.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:
CSS:

```
.test {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:500px;
}
.test li {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="test">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to `float: left` and set the `li width to 20%` of your total width (maybe slightly less).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested list. CSS allows lists to be made inline by using `display: inline` and `list-style-type: none`. If you give every `li` element to be listed horizontally these properties you can list them side by side.

Hope  this helps

James

Comment: That would change the semantics of your html, so that's not an ideal solution.  For once somebody is asking for a non-intrusive way to do layout with proper html you'd better leave it so :)